# Can I republish my app under a different account?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I'd like to republish my app using the same package name under a different account. Can this be done?

**Background:**
I have read many posts about people post about how they lost their keystore or were banned, and the solution provided to them was to republish their app using a new package name and a new keystore. This is not my situation or what I'm looking to do. I do have my password(s)/keystore.

**The motivation:**
I have published about a half dozen apps to the market, and now that they are growing in user base, I have realized it was a mistake to publish under my personal google account and now wish to do things as a company/LLC to protect my personal assets/account. To that end, I want to effectively transfer the app to another account. using a new wallet account, admob, etc.
I imagine this would be done by unpublishing from my personal account, resigning and then uploading under a new account.

**Policy Considerations:**
For those people that have been banned, they are obviously breaking some kind of terms of service by republishing the same thing. I am in good standing with Google currently and don't want to risk anything that might make them upset or give reason to ban. I can not figure out whether or not this is against their TOS/policies. Especially since I am trying to migrate towards that they were advocating.

(As an aside, if it were trivially possible, why wouldn't a malicious user publish the same content under numerous accounts?)

**Goal:**
Retain userbase and package ID so that when I release new versions under the new account all existing users on my personal account will receive those updates.

**Resources:**

- Developer Program Policy; https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html
- Developer Distribution Agreement; https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

(There are other agreements but those two seem most relevant)

**Summary question:** Can I accomplish this transfer without losing users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper I have discovered this

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986

Which may be the answer to transferring. I haven't done it yet, though. Plan to respond when I know it works.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I checked the answer to indicate, but this will comment will cement it. I'd further add that I followed every step including unpublishing and then filled out the form which took aprox. 24 hrs to complete.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to transfer the ownership of your apps from one account to another in google play store. I found a [blog post](http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/) that tells you the steps to do so:

> - [Visit this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing)
> - Fill out the form  completely and accurately
> - Select “Transfer Applications to Another Account” from the Issue Type drop down
> - Submit Form
> - Check your E-Mail and reply with the requested information
> - Forward the E-Mail to the person accepting the app/game transfer and have them reply as requested
> - Wait for Google to wave their magic wand

Comment: This form does not seem to match the blog. The Option "Transfer App to Another Account" is not even available. It also asks for a specific package name. Im worried this is the form to transfer *purchased* apps or games. While I am the developer/seller.

Comment: If you followed the steps in the blog post, It will [redirect](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601) you to the same link you mentioned in your answer